# Spell Checking With Recursive Binary Search - StackOverflow

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, binary-search

I have this recursive Binary Search Spellchecker method. sArray holds a list of words in the England dictionary. Key is any word you can send. The method will take any word(key) and look for it in the dictionary (sArray) using a recursive binary search.

I am unsure that my recursive step is correct, where I add/subtract 1 from mid for the new high/low index. However, when I run the program I get a stack overflow error which indicates my recursion doesn't stop. Below is the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1173)
at java.lang.String.compareToIgnoreCase(String.java:1226)
at Program2.bSearch(Program2.java:111)
at Program2.bSearch(Program2.java:121)

public int bSearch(ArrayList<String> sArray, String key, int lowIndex, int highIndex) {

    if (lowIndex > highIndex) {
        System.out.println("The word was not found " + c);

        c++;
        incorrectWords++;
        return -1;
    }

    mid = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;

    if (sArray.get(mid).compareToIgnoreCase(key)==0) {
        correctWords++;
        System.out.println("The word " + sArray.get(mid) + " was found *");
        return mid;
    } else if (sArray.get(mid).compareTo(key) > 0) {

        return bSearch(sArray, key, lowIndex, mid + 1);

    } else {

        return bSearch(sArray, key, mid - 1, highIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: String.compareTo is going to fail for your search perposes if you've got a mix of capitalized and uncapitalized words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
} else if (sArray.get(mid).compareTo(key) > 0) {

    return bSearch(sArray, key, lowIndex, mid + 1);

} else {

    return bSearch(sArray, key, mid - 1, highIndex);
}
```

This would stuck when key cannot be found. It should be

```
} else if (sArray.get(mid).compareTo(key) > 0) {
    return bSearch(sArray, key, lowIndex, mid - 1);
} else {
    return bSearch(sArray, key, mid + 1, highIndex);
}
```

Note the `+1` and `-1`. The range to-be-searched should be monotonically decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the bSearch function use

```
return bSearch(sArray, key, lowIndex, mid - 1);
```

and

```
return bSearch(sArray, key, mid+1, highIndex);
```